# Multiple sequential Observables with timely delay between Each of them

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to get `google places` and as per api restriction you cannot get more than 20 places per request , and next request require `nextPageToken` of previous request.

**Problem:**

- `Zip` operator executes all requests immediately , but i need them to be sequential and timely delay of `4 seconds` between each `Observable` call
- `Delay` operator allows to wait , but what it really is that it immediately executes `Zip` calls and return me results after given time in delay which is not desired.

**My Source:**

```
LatLng some = new LatLng(31.471199, 74.234940);
Observable
        .zip(getNearByPlaces(some), getNearByPlaces(some), getNearByPlaces(some), new Func3<List<PlaceInfo>, List<PlaceInfo>, List<PlaceInfo>, List<PlaceInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public List<PlaceInfo> call(List<PlaceInfo> placeInfos, List<PlaceInfo> placeInfos2, List<PlaceInfo> placeInfos3) {
                placeInfos2.addAll(placeInfos3);
                placeInfos.addAll(placeInfos2);
                return placeInfos;
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<List<PlaceInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<PlaceInfo> placeInfos) {
                adapter.setPlaces(placeInfos);
            }
        });
```

I'm beginner and started using rxjava for about 1 week ago , so you can expect mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have following response model

```
class Response {
    private String pageToken;
    private List<PlaceInfo> places;

    //setters, getters etc
}
```

And you have two methods to work with API

```
Observable<Response> getNearByPlaces(LatLng latLng) {...}
Observable<Response> getNextNearByPlaces(String pageToken) {...}
```

Define `Transformer` to fetch additional places. It waits for 4 seconds, then fetches next places and adds source places into response.

```
private Observable.Transformer<Response, Response> addNextPlaces() {
    return observable -> observable
            .delay(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(sourceResponse -> getNextNearByPlaces(sourceResponse.getPageToken()),
                    ((sourceResponse, nextResponse) -> {
                        nextResponse.getPlaces().addAll(sourceResponse.getPlaces());
                        return responseNext;
                    }));
}
```

Then you can do what you need this way

```
getNearByPlaces(latLng)
        .compose(addNextPlaces())
        //add here additional compose methods if you need them
        .subscribe(resultResponse -> {
            resultResponse.getPlaces() //handle result List
        }, error -> {
            //handle error
        });
```

P.S. Be aware about threading. `delay` switches Scheduler to `computation`

P.P.S. I suspect that there is a more simple and graceful solution :)

Comment: Thanks , it worked , just one last problem is that its a three request process  , but above sample is handling 2 request i suppose

Comment: `.compose(addNextPlaces())` adds one additional request, so if you want to chain more requests - just copy-paste this string and place it below